# Separate output values from a single grok query?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, grok

I've been capturing web logs using logstash, and specifically I'm trying to capture web URLs, but also split them up.

If I take an example log entry URL:
`"GET https://www.stackoverflow.com:443/some/link/here.html HTTP/1.1"`

I use this grok pattern:

```
\"(?:%{NOTSPACE:http_method}|-)(?:%{SPACE}http://)?(?:%{SPACE}https://)?(%{NOTSPACE:http_site}:)?(?:%{NUMBER:http_site_port:int})?(?:%{GREEDYDATA:http_site_url})? (?:%{WORD:http_type|-}/)?(?:%{NOTSPACE:http_version:float})?(?:%{SPACE})?\"
```

I get this:

```
{
  "http_method": [
    [
      "GET"
    ]
  ],
  "SPACE": [
    [
      " ",
      null,
      ""
    ]
  ],
  "http_site": [
    [
      "www.stackoverflow.com"
    ]
  ],
  "BASE10NUM": [
    [
      "443"
    ]
  ],
  "http_site_url": [
    [
      "/some/link/here.html"
    ]
  ],
  "http_type": [
    [
      "HTTP"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The trouble is, I'm trying to ***ALSO*** capture the entire URL:
`https://www.stackoverflow.com:443/some/link/here.html`

So in total, I'm seeking 4 separate outputs:

`http_site_complete` https://www.stackoverflow.com:443/some/link/here.html

`http_site` www.stackoverflow.com

`http_site_port` 443

`http_site_url` /some/link/here.html

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look at the built-in patterns for dealing with URLs.  Putting something like URIHOST in your pattern will be easier to read and maintain that a bunch od WORDs or NOTSPACEs.

Second, once you have lots of little fields, you can always use logstash's filters to manipulate them.  You could use:

```
 mutate {
     add_field => { "http_site_complete", "%{http_site}:%{http_site_port}%{http_site_url}" }
     }
 }
```

Or you could get fancy with your regexp and use a named group:

```
(?<total>%{WORD:wordOne} %{WORD:wordTwo} %{WORD:wordThree})
```

which would individually capture three fields and make one more field from the whole string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I worked this out already but I came back to upvote. :)